# How to create a variable based on the values from more than one column in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has three variables with the valid values of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 for each variable. If there isn't a numeric value assigned to the variable, it will show `NA`. The data frame `a` looks like below:

```
   ak_eth co_eth pa_eth
1     NA      1     NA
2     NA     NA      1
3     NA     NA     NA
4      2     NA     NA
5     NA     NA      4
6     NA     NA     NA
```

Each row could have `NA` across all three variables or have only one value in one of the three variables. I want to create a new variable called `recode` that takes values from the existing three variables. If all three existing variables are `NA`, the new value is `NA`; if one of the three existing variables has a value, then take that value for the new variable. 
I've tried this, but it seems didn't work for me.

```
a$recode[is.na(a$ak_eth) & is.na(a$co_eth) & is.na(a$pa_eth)] <- "NA"
library(car)
a$recode <- recode(a$ak_eth, "1=1;2=2;3=3;4=4;5=5;6=6;7=7")
a$recode <- recode(a$co_eth, "1=1;2=2;3=3;4=4;5=5;6=6;7=7")
a$recode <- recode(a$pa_eth, "1=1;2=2;3=3;4=4;5=5;6=6;7=7")
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do not create a character `"NA"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `pmax`

```
a$Recode_Var <-  do.call(pmax, c(a, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Or use `pmin`

```
a$Recode_Var <- do.call(pmin, c(a, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or another option is `rowSums`

```
r1 <- rowSums(a, na.rm = TRUE)
a$Recode_Var <- replace(r1, r1==0, NA)
```

NOTE: According to the OP's post `Each row could have NA across all three variables or have only one value in one of the three variables`

Comment: Thanks very much. All the solutions worked with my data frame. If possible, can you explain why my codes didn't work, especially the recode function in the car package.

Comment: @littlestraw It is kind of replacing the `recode` three times based on the results from 3 columns, so, the output from the first or second are lost by assigning it to `recode`